# Android ViewPager doesn't show any view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I have added a view pager in my Linearlayout like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_view_bg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/memberRegion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/doctor_location" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/memberLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/availabilityPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And wrote the code of the adapter as below :

```
package eng.hasan.medico;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import java.sql.Time;

public class AvailabilityPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    int innserSearchedDocIndex;
    AvailabilityPagerAdapter(int searchedDocIndex){
        innserSearchedDocIndex = searchedDocIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Globals.searchedDocs.get(innserSearchedDocIndex).availabilities.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int i) {
        LayoutInflater lI = (LayoutInflater) Globals.memberPageGlobalObject.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = lI.inflate(R.layout.availability_item ,view ,true);
        TextView availabilityDay = v.findViewById(R.id.availabilityDay);
        String[] days = {"فارغ", "السبت", "الأحد", "الاثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة"};
        availabilityDay.setText(days[Integer.parseInt(Globals.searchedDocs.get(innserSearchedDocIndex).availabilities.get(i).get(0))]);
        TextView availabilityTime = v.findViewById(R.id.availabilityTime);
        Time avTimeFrom = Time.valueOf(Globals.searchedDocs.get(innserSearchedDocIndex).availabilities.get(i).get(1));
        Time avTimeTo = Time.valueOf(Globals.searchedDocs.get(innserSearchedDocIndex).availabilities.get(i).get(2));
        availabilityTime.setText(avTimeFrom.toString() + "\n" + avTimeTo);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the view in each page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/availabilityDay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/left_right_top_rounded_corner"
        android:text="السبت" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/availabilityTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="3 م \n إلى \n 9 م" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/availabilityReserve"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/left_right_bottom_rounded_corner_red"
        android:text="احجز" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The program works correctly with no errors but the view pager does not display any page I tried to use (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) which has worked with me in the past but with the new version of android studio (3.5) and new SDK did not work .I have in my Gradle (minSdkVersion 19 ,targetSdkVersion 29 ,compileSdkVersion 29),please tell me if I did some wrong thing ?

The Activity which contains the ListView inside witch the ViewPager is (Java code)

```
package eng.hasan.medico;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MemberPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    String title = "بيانات الدكتور";
    ListView memberList;
    TextView innerMemberInfo;
    ProgressBar docInfoProgressBar;
    ProgressBar headerProgressBar;
    ImageView userLikeButton;
    RatingBar docRatingBar;
    boolean userSignedIn = false;
    public boolean docLiked;
    public boolean docRated;
    public int views ;
    public float rate;
    boolean RATING_MODE = false;
    ViewPager avPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_member_page);
        Globals.memberPageGlobalObject = this;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        setActivityTitle();
        rate = 0;
        checkUserLiked();
        views = Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras()
                .getInt("docObjIndex")).views;
        setMemberList();
        /*Toast.makeText(this ,String.valueOf(Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras()
                .getInt("docObjIndex")).availabilities.get(0).size()) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/




        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setMemberList(){
        memberList = findViewById(R.id.memberList);
        memberList.setAdapter(new MemberListArrayAdapter(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex")
                ,docLiked));
    }

    private void checkUserLiked(){
        if(!userSignedIn){
            File liked = new File(getFilesDir() + "/likes");
            if(liked.exists()){
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("likes")));
                    String line;
                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        int pos = 0;
                        for(int i = 0 ;i < line.length() ;i++){
                            if(line.substring(i ,i + 1).equals("-")){
                                pos = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        int docId = Integer.parseInt(Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex"))
                                .docId);
                        if(line.substring(0 ,pos).equals(String.valueOf(docId))){
                            docLiked = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    br.close();
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    docLiked = false;
                    //Toast.makeText(this ,"خطأ فتح الملف" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    docLiked = false;
                    //Toast.makeText(this ,"خطأ فتح الذاكرة" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else {
                docLiked = false;
                //Toast.makeText(this ,"الملف غير موجود" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        checkUserRated();
    }

    private void checkUserRated(){
        if(!userSignedIn){
            File liked = new File(getFilesDir() + "/rates");
            if(liked.exists()){
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("rates")));
                    String line;
                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        int pos = 0;
                        for(int i = 0 ;i < line.length() ;i++){
                            if(line.substring(i ,i + 1).equals("-")){
                                pos = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        int docId = Integer.parseInt(Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex"))
                                .docId);
                        if(line.substring(0 ,pos).equals(String.valueOf(docId))){
                            rate = Float.parseFloat(line.substring(pos + 1 ,line.length()));
                            docRated = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    br.close();
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    docRated = false;
                    //Toast.makeText(this ,"خطأ فتح الملف" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    docRated = false;
                    //Toast.makeText(this ,"خطأ فتح الذاكرة" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else {
                docRated = false;
                //Toast.makeText(this ,"الملف غير موجود" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setActivityTitle(){
        LayoutInflater lI = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = lI.inflate(R.layout.activity_title ,null ,false);
        TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.activityTitle);
        tv.setText(title);
        headerProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.titleProgressBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
    }

    public void loadMemberInfo(TextView memberInfo ,String memberId){
        innerMemberInfo = memberInfo;
        new Thread(new GetMemberInfo (memberId)).start();
    }

    public void showMemberInfo(JSONArray info){
       if(info.length() > 0){
           String processedInfo = "<ul>";
           try {
               for(int i = 0 ;i < info.length() ;i++){
                   processedInfo += "<li>" + info.getJSONObject(i).getString("info") + "</li>";
               }
               processedInfo += "</ul>";
               innerMemberInfo.setText(Html.fromHtml(processedInfo));
           }catch (JSONException e){

           }

       }
    }

    public void hideInfoProgressBar(){
        docInfoProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        if(!userSignedIn){
            new Thread(new RecordDocView(0 ,
                    Integer.parseInt(Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex"))
                            .docId))).start();
        }
    }

    public void hideHeaderProgressBar(){
        headerProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void assignInfoPBar(ProgressBar bar){
        docInfoProgressBar = bar;
    }

    public  void recordUserLike(){
        if(!userSignedIn){
            new Thread(new RecordUserLike(0 ,
                    Integer.parseInt(Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex"))
                            .docId))).start();
            headerProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void recordUserUnlike(){
        int likeId = -1;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("likes")));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                int pos = 0;
                for(int i = 0 ;i < line.length() ;i++){
                    if(line.substring(i ,i + 1).equals("-")){
                        pos = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                int docId = Integer.parseInt(Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex"))
                        .docId);
                if(line.substring(0 ,pos).equals(String.valueOf(docId))){
                    likeId = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(pos + 1 ,line.length()));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e){

        }
        new Thread(new RecordUserLike(likeId)).start();
        headerProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void assignUserLikeButton(ImageView likeButton){
        userLikeButton = likeButton;
    }

    public void processLiked(int likeId ,int docId){
       if(!userSignedIn){
           userLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_solid);
           OutputStreamWriter oSW ;
           if(!userSignedIn){
               try {
                   oSW = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("likes" ,MODE_APPEND));
                   oSW.append( docId + "-" + likeId);
                   oSW.append("\n\r");
                   oSW.flush();
                   oSW.close();
               }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                   Toast.makeText(this ,"خطأ فتح الملف" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }catch (IOException e) {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "خطأ فتح الذاكرة", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       }
    }

    public void processUnliked(int likeId){
       if(!userSignedIn){
           File inputFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "/likes");
           File tempFile = new File(getFilesDir() +  "/likes_temp");

           try {
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
               BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

               String lineToRemove = Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex")).docId
                       + "-" + likeId;
               String currentLine;

               while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                   String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                   if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
                   writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
               }
               writer.close();
               reader.close();
               tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
           }catch (IOException e){

           }
           userLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
       }
    }

    public void recordRating(final float value){
        RATING_MODE = true;
        headerProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        LayoutInflater lI = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       if (!userSignedIn){
           final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this ,R.style.MyDialogTheme).create();
          if(!docRated){
              View alertView = lI.inflate(R.layout.rate_doc_alert ,null ,false);
              alertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
              ((TextView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.rateAlertMessage)).setText("هل تود اختيار التقييم : " +
                      value + " لهذه الصفحة");
              ((Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.alertPositiveButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View view) {
                      new Thread(new RecordRating(Globals.searchedDocs.get(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex")).docId
                              ,value ,0)).start();
                      alert.dismiss();
                      RATING_MODE = true;
                  }
              });
              ((Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.alertNegativeButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View view) {
                      alert.dismiss();
                      hideHeaderProgressBar();
                      docRatingBar.setRating(0);
                      RATING_MODE = false;
                  }
              });
              alert.setView(alertView);
              alert.show();
          }else{

              View alertView = lI.inflate(R.layout.rate_doc_alert ,null ,false);
              alertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
              ((TextView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.rateAlertMessage)).setText("لقد قمت بالفعل بتقييم هذه الصفحة");
              ((Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.alertPositiveButton)).setEnabled(false);
              ((Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.alertNegativeButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View view) {
                      alert.dismiss();
                      docRatingBar.setRating(rate);
                      RATING_MODE = false;
                      hideHeaderProgressBar();
                  }
              });
              alert.setView(alertView);
              alert.setCancelable(false);
              alert.show();
          }
       }
    }

    public void processRated(int docId , float rateVal){
        OutputStreamWriter oSW ;
        if(!userSignedIn){
            try {
                oSW = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("rates" ,MODE_APPEND));
                oSW.append( docId + "-" + rateVal);
                oSW.append("\n\r");
                oSW.flush();
                oSW.close();
                docRated = true;
                docRatingBar.setRating(rateVal);
                RATING_MODE = false;
                rate = rateVal;

            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                Toast.makeText(this ,"خطأ فتح الملف" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                resetRating();

            }catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "خطأ فتح الذاكرة", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                resetRating();
            }
        }
    }

    public void assignRateBar(RatingBar bar){
        docRatingBar = bar;
    }

    public void assignAvViewPager(ViewPager vP){
        avPager = vP;
        avPager.setAdapter(new AvailabilityPagerAdapter(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex") ,getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    public boolean isRatingModeOn(){
        return RATING_MODE;
    }

    public void resetRating(){
        docRatingBar.setRating(0);
        RATING_MODE = false;
    }
}
```

and here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    tools:context="eng.hasan.medico.MemberPage">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/memberList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/memberCustomersRatings"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="تقييمات الزائرين"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_corners_bg"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between your Adapter Constructor and how you call it from that Activity:

```
AvailabilityPagerAdapter(int searchedDocIndex)
```

and

```
AvailabilityPagerAdapter(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("docObjIndex") ,getSupportFragmentManager())
```

And without proper Context an Adapter doesn't know where to show content